# When installing an IPA on my test device, the app is stuck in "Waiting..." How do I fix this?

Tags: testing, provisioning, ipa

I am a tester with limited knowledge. My developer has distributed the app to me for testing but I can't get the app to finish installation on my device. I'm running iOS 9.2.

The developer has added my UDID to the provisioning profile and sent me that IPA. He says he's done it this way many times before with success, and doesn't know what the problem is.

I drag the IPA into iTunes and sync the device. The app appears on my screen, but is stuck on either "Installing..." Or "Waiting..."

It's there anything I'm missing on my end our something I can double check to make sure I'm doing right? Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely looks provisioning issue. Tell your developer counterpart to provide you build via TestFlight. In Testflight, you should get invite first for accessing the build and then it will be easier for both of you in long run.

https://developer.apple.com/testflight/